# Are there other articles by Ada Lovelace than translation of Menabrea's notes on Analytical Engine?

Tags: computer-science, computers

Ada Lovelace is well known as an translator of Luigi's Menabrea article on Babbage's Analytical engine. She also added notes to the translation which are in the end longer than the translation itself. Somebody even considers these notes to be basics of modern computing.

In the book *Grace Hopper: Admiral of Cyber Sea* by Kathleen B. Williams, the author stated that Howard Aiken wanted Grace Hopper to study Babbage's and Lovelace's articles to better understnad computing. This leads me to question **if there are another Ada's articles than the Notes on Analytical Engine**.